# NotifyTaskCompletion Xamarin UI in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, inotifytaskcompletion

I´ve a question regarding INotifyTaskCompletion (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

When i use this patter in an UI, created in XAML everything works fine.
But when i want to use it in a UI generated by Code (C#) it doesen´t work.
Viewmodel is the same.

I have have a Test project in this Link.
https://github.com/marcuskammerlander/NotifyTaskCompletion

You can change the UI in App.xaml.cs

```
public Testpage()
    {


        //Work
        this.BindingContext = new testpageViewModel();
        TestCount.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("UrlByteCount.Result", BindingMode.OneWay));

        //Doesent Work
        //testpageViewModel viewModel = new testpageViewModel();
        //this.BindingContext = viewModel;
        //TestCount.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(viewModel.UrlByteCount.Result), BindingMode.OneWay));


        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                TestLabel, TestCount
            }
        };
    }
```

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: You need to include the problematic code within your question itself, not via an offsite resource.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I do not get fully your question. Could you describe it more detailed? I download github code and it seems to run correctly. One thing which should not be done is `Text="{Binding UrlByteCount.Result}"`. Instead of using `.Result` you should consider binding it from backend and display progress indicator until it is not completed.

Comment: Hi Jan, i added some code. Yes normally there is a Loading indicator. it´s just a minimal test to investigate the Problem. It is not a blueprint for further use.